# How Can I create a graph using this samples?

Tags: r

I'm a complete novice in R and I've been trying to create a graph in R without any excel data. I only have these:

```
SampleA=c(963.25, 960.09, 971.81, 954.87, 967.2, 974.03, 948.34, 928.64, 943.09,
967.35, 928.93, 955.64, 973.28, 964.59, 928.48, 957.1)

SampleB=c(1975.56, 1961.6, 1924.5, 1926.01, 1932.9, 1926.17, 1964.78, 1927.42, 1934.92,
1954.09, 1944.11, 1934.97, 1937.15, 1939.11, 1935.36, 1961.17)
```

how can I use a pivot_longer to make a columns for it? And What kind of graph should I use in order to see the difference between these two sample.

I tried doing these:

```
df <- data.frame (
  Sample = "Sample A", "Sample B",
  Days = SampleA, SampleB
)
pivot_longer(df, Sample = "SampleA", "SampleB", Days = Sample)
```

but I get this error

```
Error: 2 components of `...` were not used. We detected these problematic arguments: * `Sample` * `Days` Did you misspecify an argument?
```

Comment: Please check your `data.frame` call.  I think you want `df <- data.frame(Sample = rep(c("Sample A", "Sample B"), c(length(SampleA), length(SampleB))), Days = c(SampleA, SampleB))`

Comment: Oh it worked. Thank you. Is there any graph that you can recommend to use on how i can see the difference between these samples?

Comment: I posted a solution below.  Please check if that works for you. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to test if values are different reckons to statistical measures. You can use box plots in order to check if the samples are different or equal. Or maybe a t-test as your variable is continuous with two groups. Here a code for box plots:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=Sample,y=Days,fill=Sample))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_boxplot()+
  facet_wrap(.~Sample,scales = 'free')
```

Output:

[image]

Based on our box plots and the mean (middle bar in each box) it looks like values across samples are different. We can confirm that with a t-test:

```
#Test
t.test(df$Days[df$Sample=='Sample A'],df$Days[df$Sample=='Sample B'])$p.value
```

Output:

```
[1] 9.124026e-47
```

As our p-value is extremely low we can support the hypothesis that values across  samples are different.

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(Sample = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Sample A", "Sample B"
), class = "factor"), Days = c(963.25, 960.09, 971.81, 954.87, 
967.2, 974.03, 948.34, 928.64, 943.09, 967.35, 928.93, 955.64, 
973.28, 964.59, 928.48, 957.1, 1975.56, 1961.6, 1924.5, 1926.01, 
1932.9, 1926.17, 1964.78, 1927.42, 1934.92, 1954.09, 1944.11, 
1934.97, 1937.15, 1939.11, 1935.36, 1961.17)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-32L))
```

Answer (score 0):

After create the 'df', we can use `ggplot` with 'Days' on the y axis and the row sequence on the x axis with `color` as 'Sample'

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(Sample) %>% 
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
   ggplot(., aes(x = rn, y = Days, color = Sample)) + 
      geom_line()
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(Sample = rep(c("Sample A", "Sample B"), 
      c(length(SampleA), length(SampleB))), Days = c(SampleA, SampleB))
```